# calculate sumproduct(Excel) in pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe.Structure:

```
SEQ     product_name prod_cost  non-prd_cost mgmt    grand_total
1       prod1           100       200         20        320
2       prod2           200       400         30        630
3       prod3           300       500         40        840
4       prod4           100       300         50        450
```

I want to calculate sumproduct(in excel) based on condition.The condition is based on product_name.

lets say I want to calculate a variable called

```
sumprod_prod1_prd_prod3_mgmt = SUMPRODUCT(SEQ 1-4,product_name='prod1'_prod_cost and 'prod3'_mgmt)/2  = 100+40=140
```

How can I do this in pandas?

Comment: use a groupby or a pivot table in pandas. show the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am a bit confused by your question, since the excel SUMPRODUCT function returns the sum of the products of corresponding ranges or arrays, and you seem to want the SUM of a singular combination.
To get the desired value:

```
sumprod_prod1_prd_prod3_mgmt = df[df['product_name'] == 'prod1']['prod_cost'].values[0]+df[df['prod_name']=='prod3']['mgmt'].values[0]
```

This solution gives a single result for the specified values.  If you need a solution which provides the same functionality as excel, please update your question and example to better define what you are looking for.